# C# MongoDB driver logging invalid certificate even though queries work

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, ssl, .net-core

I'm using the MongoDB driver with C# to work with a MongoDB cluster on Digital Ocean. All MongoDB clusters on Digital Ocean use self-signed certs. I have working code for using the CA certificate they provide when connecting to MongoDB. These settings work. I can read and write to the database just fine from within the application.

For reference, here's the code handling the Mongo connection:

```
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace App.src.Common
{
  public class MongoClientFactory
  {
    private X509Certificate? ca;

    private readonly ILogger logger;

    // MongoDB driver uses the same connection pool for client connections created with the
    // same settings. To ensure this, always pass in the same reference to the driver as the
    // one that was first instantiated with this class.
    private readonly MongoClientSettings settings;

    public MongoClientFactory(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<MongoClientFactory> logger)
    {
      this.logger = logger;

      IConfigurationSection config = configuration.GetSection("MongoSettings");

      // TODO: change this key to something more descriptive of what it actually is.
      settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(configuration.GetConnectionString("Bukkit"));

      string path = config["CACertificatePath"];
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
      {
        this.ca = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(path);
        this.logger.LogDebug($"CA certificate read successfully from {path}");

        settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings
        {
          ServerCertificateValidationCallback = this.ValidateServerCertificate
        };

        this.logger.LogDebug("CA certificate detected, SSL settings set to handle validation");
      }
    }

    public MongoClient NewClient()
    {
      this.logger.LogDebug($"connecting to mongo at {settings.Server}");

      return new MongoClient(settings);
    }

    private bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate? cert, X509Chain? chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
      if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
      {
        this.logger.LogDebug("found no SSL policy errors, cert valid");
        return true;
      }

      if (this.ca == null)
      {
        this.logger.LogError("loaded CA certificate is null, cert invalid");
        return false;
      }

      if (chain == null)
      {
        this.logger.LogError("certificate chain is null, cert invalid");
        return false;
      }

      // I guess the root is the last certificate in the chain???
      X509ChainElement root = chain.ChainElements[chain.ChainElements.Count - 1];

      if (this.ca.GetRawCertDataString().Equals(root.Certificate.GetRawCertDataString()))
      {
        this.logger.LogDebug("certificate root matches loaded ca certificate, cert valid");
        return true;
      }

      this.logger.LogWarning($"CA cert didn't match");
      this.logger.LogWarning($"SSL policy error {sslPolicyErrors} cannot be handled");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

In my logs, I see the messages confirming everything is working. I see this for every query:

```
certificate root matches loaded ca certificate, cert valid
```

However, my logs are also polluted with this:

```
fail: App.src.Filters.JsonExceptionFilter[0]
      Unhandled Exception: System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "2", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 2, EndPoint : "Unspecified/REDACTED:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/REDACTED:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
         at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2022-03-11T20:56:09.1136007Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2022-03-11T20:56:09.1136011Z" }] }.
         at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
         at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
         at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedAsync(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServerAsync(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAfterServerSelectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.StartImplicitSessionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToListAsync[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Bukkit.src.Repositories.FeatureToggleRepository.FindAllAsync(Expression`1 filter, Nullable`1 page, Nullable`1 size, Expression`1 sort, SortOrder sortOrder) in /app/src/Repositories/FeatureToggleRepository.cs:line 70
         at Bukkit.src.Services.FeatureToggleService.GetEnabledFeatureToggles() in /app/src/Services/FeatureToggleService.cs:line 61
         at Bukkit.src.Controllers.FeatureToggleController.GetEnabledToggles() in /app/src/Controllers/FeatureToggleController.cs:line 37
         at lambda_method29(Closure , Object )
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
```

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

After going nuts over this for a while, I happened to open a file for a class that was creating Mongo clients without using the `MongoClientFactory` above. Changing that worked.